# How can I retrieve second data from array list

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I can only retrieve first data "9780071792745" from my database. The app crashed when I tried to retrieve data from b. Here is my code

```
public class wish_list extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView display;

    //private String wishlist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wish_list);

        display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        //start here
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());//got all wish list item from database
                    String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
                    String b = wishlist_item.get(1);

                    display.setText("Hi" + a);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can only retrieve from `String a = wishlist_item.get(0)` and cannot retrieve from `String b = wishlist_item.get(1);`

How can I retrieve?

Here is my data structure from my firebase database:

[image]

I can also tried to retrieve like this `display.setText("Hi" + wishlist_item);` and it worked but cannot retrieve from `display.setText("Hi" + b);`

error is :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Comment: Please post the Crash log, it will be easier to understand your problem

Comment: error is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437) @SoumikBhattacharjee

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrive data from index 1 while that index is not created yet. When you enter the for loop, the for loop is getting the first item from the snapshot and adding it to the wishlist_item arraylist. What you need to do is this:

```
List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<String>();
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
     wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());//got all wish list item from database
}
String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
String b = wishlist_item.get(1);

display.setText("Hi" + a);
```

This will work. Because you let your foreach loop to finish. This line:

```
wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());//got all wish list item from database
```

won't put all items from a snapshot, it will add one item at the time, the one that foreach loop is using right now. You first need to understand how for and foreach loops work: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/

Comment: I still cannot find out sir can u help me pls.

Comment: I told you above why you get that error. You are trying to get the value from index 1 while you only have 1 element inside your ArrayList which is at index 0. That's why you got IndexOutOfBounds: Index: 1, Size: 1. You need to leave your foreach loop to finish and then populate your ArrayList. After that you can get elements from ArrayList from wishlist_item.get(0) to wishlist_item.get(wishlist_item.size() - 1). Also, you need to be sure that the user you are getting a wishlist from has more than one wishlist inside the database.